# can I finetune a model on Azure for information extraction based on "question", "context", and "answer" training data?

Tags: large-language-models, fine-tuning

I am working on extracting certain fields from a large corpus.

I was looking at finetuning an LLM on Azure for the task. I think finetuning is the right idea (as opposed to vector databases, or RAG), since the data was OCR'd from semi-structured forms, and has been tokenized into a less-than-ideal natural language structure.

So I have a dataset in this form:

```
{"prompt": "find the date in this text", context: "chickens can't fly, blue red green, asdkjfek, Nov 11 2011", "completion": ""Nov 11 2022"}
```

I want zero generation or creativity in this task -- merely extraction.

For finetuning in Azure, the recommended structure is this:

```
{"prompt": "<prompt text>", "completion": "<ideal generated text>"}
```

I'm not sure finetuning will be effective if I include context with my prompt. I'd basically be doing "in-context finetuning", so to speak. Not sure that's a thing. I've done a lot of [reading], yet still not sure if it makes sense.

Any advice greatly appreciated.